# TYPO3 File Abstraction Layer FILES listNum

Tags: typo3, typo3-6.1.x

I have a menu and want to access on media files from the page configurations. This works quite well, but it gives all the images of the media files. ListNum it does not work. Do you have an idea or an alternative solution? Important I want to use file:current:description and file:current:title

```
after.cObject = FILES
after.cObject {
references {
    table = pages
    fieldName = media
    # listNum = 1 not working
}
renderObj = IMAGE
renderObj {
    file.import.data = file:current:originalUid
    file.width = 250
    file.import.listNum = 1
    altText.data = file:current:description
}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The code of the OP and of maholtz's answer does not work in current TYPO3 versions any more. Here is the correct TypoScript for 6.2 and beyond:

```
1 = TMENU
1 {
    wrap = <ul>|</ul>
    NO = 1
    NO {
        wrapItemAndSub = <li>|</li>

        stdWrap.override.cObject = FILES
        stdWrap.override.cObject {
          references {
            table = pages
            fieldName = media
          }

          renderObj = IMAGE
          renderObj {
            file.import.data = file:current:uid
            file.treatIdAsReference = 1
            titleText.data = file:current:title // field:nav_title // field:title
            altText.data = file:current:alternative // field:nav_title // field:title
          }

          # start with second image
          begin = 1
          # show only one image
          maxItems = 1
        }

    }
}
```

The parameter `begin` defines which of multiple images should be used (e.g. if you need one image as a headline background for the page and another one as an icon in the menus).

If you increase the `maxItems` parameter, multiple images will be returned (if multiple images are defined in the resources tab).

If you want to append/prepend the image to the menu text instead of replacing it, you have to change `stdWrap.override.cObject` to `after.cObject` or `before.cObject` in the above code.

Answer (score 0):

```
after.cObject = FILES
after.cObject {
  references {
    table = pages
    fieldName = media
    # listNum = 1 not working
  }
  renderObj = IMAGE
  renderObj {
    file.import.data = file:current:originalUid
    file.width = 250
    file.import.listNum = 1
    altText.data = file:current:description
  }
  # start with first image
  begin = 0
  # show only two images
  maxItems = 2
}
```

There are two registered filled:

```
REGISTER:FILES_COUNT
```

and

```
REGISTER:FILE_NUM_CURRENT
```

Implemented in typo3/sysext/frontend/Classes/ContentObject/FilesContentObject.php

Comment: That works only with TYPO3 6.2. [link](http://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/latest/ContentObjects/Files/Index.html) Is there a solution for 6.1?

Comment: renderObj.stdWrap.if.equals = 1 <br> renderObj.stdWrap.if.value.data = REGISTER:FILE_NUM_CURRENT (if the REGISTERS are allready there)

Comment: if the Register is not there, you could wrap the IMAGES with an special Marker and split the marker with after.split - then you are able to define which object you should get. Please check if the REGISTERS are there, if not i will try to add an expamle for this

Comment: is there may be a possibility to use LOAD_REGISTER and then split the string

Answer (score 0):

Here comes another example with stacked image references. This code can be used with jquerypicture.

```
lib.headerImg = COA
lib.headerImg.wrap =  <picture alt="some alttext">|</picture>
lib.headerImg {

    // <source>
    10 = FILES
    10 {

      references {
        table = pages
        uid.data = tsfe:id
        fieldName = media
      }

      renderObj = IMG_RESOURCE
      renderObj {
          file.import.data = file:current:uid
          file.treatIdAsReference = 1
          stdWrap.dataWrap = <source src="|">
          # the 2nd pic gets another attribute
          stdWrap.dataWrap.override = <source src="|" media="(min-width:600px)">
          stdWrap.dataWrap.override.if.value = 1
          stdWrap.dataWrap.override.if.equals.data = register:FILE_NUM_CURRENT
          # altText.data = file:current:title
      }

      begin = 0
      maxItems = 2

    }

    // <noscript>
    20 < .10
    20.begin = 1
    20.maxItems = 1
    20.renderObj.stdWrap.dataWrap = <noscript><img src="|" alt="{file:current:title}"></noscript>


}
```